# django don't allow a user to access a page

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class DashboardNewProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    template_name = 'profile/profile_create.html'

    def _usercheck(self):
        u = self.request.user
        qs = Profile.objects.all().filter(u)
        if qs is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/create/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/view/')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(DashboardNewProfile, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        kwargs.update({'slug': self.request.user.username})
        return kwargs
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/create/$', views.DashboardNewProfile.as_view(), name="new_profile"),
```

How do i do the following?
If the logged in user already has a profile associated with a profile object in the database. i dont want the user to access the URL ('/profile/create/') insted i want the user to be automatically redirected to another url ('/profile/view')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change what `LoginRequiredMixin` does, you would need to override the `dispatch` method which is where it checks if the user is logged in. It look like what you really want is the `user_passes_test` decorator:

```
def has_no_profile(user):
    # Receives the request.user object from user_passes_test
    # Note that you need to filter using model_field=value
    # Returns true if the user has no profile, false otherwise
    return not Profile.objects.filter(user=user).exists()

# Method decorator attaches the user_passes_test to the class based view
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(has_no_profile, login_url='/profile/view/'), name='dispatch')
class DashboardNewProfile(CreateView):
    ...
```

[Documentation for user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

[Documentation for method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

[Documentation for filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Note that there is also a [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) if you prefer, I just generally keep these tests separate so they can be used across other views and prefer the look of the decorator.

Comment: It works but if the user fails the test i want to redirect to another page. i can do "login_url='/profile/view/'" but i get the url as "/profile/view/?next=/profile/create/" i just need "/profile/view/

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to for 'user_passes_test', you can remove it by setting 'redirect_field_name' to None

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193018/redirect-after-login-django-registration-redux